# Yocto local repository

Tags: linux, git, yocto

In our office, employees use yocto for project development activity & all will be downloading from source repository.

I want to setup a repository kind of server (just like apt-cacher), where all client machine will connect local repository & download whatever is required. Is this possible?

Please correct if I am asking something wrong or understood wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to create a local cloud drive and attach that to the computer as a folder.

In `/conf/local.conf`, change

```
SSTATE_DIR = "/path/to/your/sstate-repository"
DL_DIR ?= "/path/to/your/download/repository"
```

Please note that sstate will build up from time to time so create a cron job to delete the file in there using this command:

`find ${sstate_dir} -name 'sstate*' -atime +3 -delete; fi`

More information can be found on page 27 [HERE](https://www.yoctoproject.org/sites/default/files/yocto_devday_advanced_class_sandiego.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the only thing you care about here is sources (and not built packages) you should probably take a look at the [`PREMIRRORS` variable](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PREMIRRORS). One thing that I'm not clear about in your question is "source repository" (accompanied with `git` label), your project is typically built from lots of components, about 95% of those come from external sources while some come from internal repositories (Git/SVN/whatever). Internal repositories are usually not a big problem, you have them nearby, they tend to work and everyone involved should have some access to them anyway. Most of the problems actually occur with external fetching, that's where mirroring is handy.

The way I usually set up things wrt source file management is as follows:

- set up some internal FTP server, say "ftp://oe-src.example.com/" (with anonymous read-only access)
- use `DL_DIR ?= "${HOME}/sources"` in your `local.conf` (which is the way it used to be way back in OE Classic days), it's not strictly necessary, it's just that I like having an ability to clean up build directory without wiping downloaded source files at the same time
- set `PREMIRRORS` variable in the `local.conf` like this:

  ```
  PREMIRRORS = "\
          git://.*/.* ftp://oe-src.example.com/ \n \
          ftp://.*/.* ftp://oe-src.example.com/ \n \
          http://.*/.* ftp://oe-src.example.com/ \n \
          https://.*/.* ftp://oe-src.example.com/ \n \
  "
  ```
- add an action to your CI tool to synchronize (in "add to" mode, not removing old sources) `~/sources` with your FTP after the build (via FTP/SCP/rsync/whatever)

This way you always have a nice set of source files (BTW, also including tarballs of VCS checkouts for your internal software, so it somewhat helps reducing the load on your internal VCS) on FTP and most of the source file requests get satisfied with this FTP, so you no longer have problems with missing sources/broken checksums/slow downloads/etc.

The only downside that I see is that this FTP is open to everyone and it has all the sources including your internal ones, which may or may not be problem depending on your security policies. This can be mitigated by using per-project SFTP mirrors, which would incur additional overhead of user key management, but I've also done such setups in practice, so when it's needed it can be done.